# Auto-update total reputation after the question/answer is voted

Tags: feature-request, reputation, live-refresh

If SO user ask a question or answer a question, when user asked/answer that question that time display on the top of the user.

For question

> asked **12 mins ago**

For comment

> this is sample comment.-  SO user name **12 mins ago**

For answer

> answered **14 mins ago**

And this time auto-updated (refreshed) via AJAX call after certain interval.
But when one user up vote/down vote on a question/answer, then the score of the user who has asked that question or answered that question not reflected until unless the page got refreshed.

***Why so? Why not the score auto-updated (refreshed) via AJAX call after certain interval like the time?***

Auto-updated should be also available for score, isn't?

[image]

Comment: What makes you think the time display is updated via AJAX calls?

Comment: Why focus so much on other users' reputation? Is there some sort of spectator sport I'm unaware of? Grab the popcorn and watch the reputation rise, or drop? Gah!! I've just had a mental picture of a stock-ticker kind of thing that shows SO users with their rising or dropping reputation.

Comment: I really don't see the use of this feature.  I'd rather just refresh the page myself.  That pushes every update, including edits to posts, comments, votes on comments, new comments.

Comment: You have missed a very important component to feature requests - why would this benefit the community.  What problem would be solved by seeing someone's reputation updated in (almost) real time?

Comment: It was just an observation and thought I should know why SO implemented like this. I think,got proper clarification, if any other points I need to know, plz let me know.

Comment: Considering server time and client time both travel at the same rate (roughly sixty seconds per minute, sixty minutes per hour, twenty four hours per day, if we can believe what we're told), there would be absolutely no reason to update times within the webpage by using ajax calls.  A simple client-side timer can update times on the page at whatever rate is desired.

Comment: @WIll time is a constant? SAYS WHO!?

Comment: @Patrice It's either the patriarchy, or the illuminati.  Outside chance it's the lizard men, but people who believe in them are pretty loony in my opinion.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Auto-updated should be also available for score, isn't?

I don't think that would be a good feature addition.

---

Reasons:

- It would be distracting. Reputation of some users could be increasing/decreasing rapidly, so a number which keeps on changing would be a big distraction.
- It would put more load on the server. Continuously updating reps and pushing it down to web browsers would be an expensive operation. Caching would become useless.
- It would increasing the bandwidth usage.